# Document Restful API created in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, documentation, swagger

I have created Restful APIs in Node.js and now I plan to document them so they can be shared with others. I spent the past couple of days researching in to this and I found [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) and started exploring what it had to offer. I really like [Swagger-UI](http://swagger.io/swagger-ui/), It takes a JSON object and generates a document as displayed by this [Demo](http://petstore.swagger.io/). Another option is using the [Swagger-Editor](http://swagger.io/swagger-editor/) however this means writing out manually and I am not interested in that.

So basically I feel if I can generate the JSON object based on docstrings/comments I write in my api .js files I can then simply pass the JSON in to swagger-UI and have my beautiful document. I was looking for some tool that can help me achieve this. Any tool or tutorial would help out a lot. I have looked at all the tools listed on [Swagger Open Source Integration Section](http://swagger.io/open-source-integrations/).

Perhaps  I missed something but would definitely appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction. I am not interested in design first approach etc. I already have existing APIs and would like to generate documents for them. I highly appreciate prompt replies from experienced users as I am really stuck on this. I have no sense of direction right now.

**Additional Notes**

I guess a perhaps a tool that can even help me create that JSON object would be a good idea but I do feel I might have missed something since swagger is so popular I am sure this must be done before.

Comment: What framework you used to create api

Comment: The thing is I have used hapijs for development there is plugin available for it. For Express swagger node express is available.  Take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found a really nice tool that does exactly what i want. I hope others can find this post useful. I found something called [api-doc swagger](https://github.com/fsbahman/apidoc-swagger). It utilizes api-doc which converts docstrings in to a json object. This api-doc swagger tool goes further and converts that json object in to swagger json format which you can then pass in to the swagger-ui.

Comment: Instead of api-doc, You can use JOI as a validator and pass the same object to Swagger for generating documentation. It will be less erroneous. https://github.com/AndrewKeig/express-validation-swagger uses this idea